# Keep getting a SyntaxError message in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

[image: My code]

What is the problem in this code?

I keep getting a `SyntaxError` on line 33, right after `print step`.

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, copy/paste the code into your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Aaron, I guess I don't know how to add the code by using ctrl+k.. I will get to that since I am very new to this.

Comment: The error message I am now getting is:

  File "ML5.py", line 30, in <module>
    for step in xrange(2001):
NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined.

Comment: I will definitely read thru how-to-ask part later. Thanks for your advice Aaron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That print statement will give you an error in Python 3.X because it is no longer a statement, it is a function call.

`print('{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(step, sess.run(cost), sess.run(W), sess.run(b)))`

See the python documentation or [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html#the-print-function) for more information.

**EDIT**: As per late comments above, try changing `xrange()` to `range()`, since `xrange` does not exist in Python 3.